# Is there a way to extract a dict in Python into the local namespace?

Tags: php, python, dictionary

PHP has a function called extract() which takes an associative array as the argument and creates local variables out of the keys whose values are assigned to the key's values. Is there a way to do this in Python? A quick google search didn't immediately show me how. I suspect there's a way with exec() but it'd be nice if there were some function to do it for me.

Comment: "Another language can do it" is rarely a good reason to implement specific functionality.

Comment: This isn't a "must have" feature for me, I just think it's kind of nifty for functions taking **kwargs.

Comment: If you statically know the names you are receiving with kwargs and can type them in the body of your function, you would not be using `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is [**not safe**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) to modify the dict that locals() returns

```
>>> d={'a':6, 'b':"hello", 'c':set()}
>>> exec '\n'.join("%s=%r"%i for i in d.items())
>>> a
6
>>> b
'hello'
>>> c
set([])
```

But using exec like this is ugly. You should redesign so you don't need to dynamically add to your local namespace

**Edit:** See Mike's reservations about using repr in the comments.

```
>>> d={'a':6, 'b':"hello", 'c':set()}
>>> exec '\n'.join("%s=d['%s']"%(k,k) for k in d)
>>> id(d['c'])
3079176684L
>>> id(c)
3079176684L
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this. I mentioned above that I don't NEED this functionality, I just think it's neat to have.

Comment: Although I don't think anyone *really* needs this functionality, one way to redesign your code would be to pass the dict into a function with **kwargs, where the dict will be cleanly unpacked into the local namespace.

Comment: This code is broken. If you were to do this, you would reference the dict itself, not pull out reprs of the objects, which doesn't work in the general case. For example, you created a new set rather than using the passed one and if I had passed you a different type, like one I made without a useful `repr`, you'd be up the creek.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for pointing that out - it is possible to use the references from the dict directly

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
    locals().update(my_dict)
```

EDIT:

`gnibbler` has made a very valid point that locals shouldn't be modified (check: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals). Still, Python docs doesn't say it's not safe, it only says that changes to locals may not affect values of variables. Before answering the question I tried in my Python's 2.6 IDLE that updating locals actually works, both in global scope and inside a function. That's why I'm not deleting my answer, but instead I'm adding a **warning** that it might work under certain (platform-specific?) circumstances, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: It's not safe to make modifications to `locals()` http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: I didn't know, do you have any link supporting this? EDIT: I found here that locals() are read-only, which is not the case in IDLE 2.6 shell...

Comment: It's not sage but it sufficient for a casual use.

Comment: Link was cut from my comment above, it was example 8.12 at: http://diveintopython.org/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html

Answer (score -1):

Modifying locals() dict could have been a solution but docs say, http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#

> Note The contents of this dictionary
>   should not be modified; changes may
>   not affect the values of local and
>   free variables used by the
>   interpreter.

so the question is why you even need it? there may be better ways to achieve that whatever you are trying to achieve.

Also why can't you directly access dict or assign them to variables?